How can I combine/pool the results of regression ANN?
In my analysis, the data contains 5 imputed dependent variables. So, after analyzing all of the dependent variables separately with a regression neural network, I need to combine/pool the results. However, I can't find how to do this. What do you think about what can I do in this situation? I would be very happy if you could help.
